# Lightning Experience lookup filters are not supported

Tags: lightning-experience, lookup-filter

Has anyone come up with a workaround for lookup filters in the `Lightning Experience`(If it is even possible)? Currently we are using a lookup filter on a lookup field on `Object C` to filter the possibilities of `Object B` to only show `B`'s that have a lookup to the same `A` record.

This is not supported in the lightning experience as described [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_lex_gaps_limitations_search.htm). And is still not coming in the Spring `16 release as per the [release notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring16_release_notes.pdf).

```
             Object A
               / \
              /   Object B
             /     \
             Object C
```

The issue is in the `Lightning Experience`, if a user starts to fill out the lookup field on a `C` record all `B` records will show up instead of the records that only have like lookup to an `A` record.

I am also curious if someone has insight to if/when Salesforce will be implementing this for the `Lightning Experience`.

Comment: Are you looking for a point and click solution or are you open to creating a custom object that would serve as a junction object "filter" to hold your screen results for you? That's the only way I can think of to do what you're asking.

Comment: @crmprogdev I considered that, but is not an than ideal solution(granted I can't think of another way either). That would introduce another level of complexity that really isn't needed. I am hoping that SF puts the lookup filters on their radar for lighting. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E0bEAAS&sort=2), which has next to no votes. But this is a known issue as stated in the release notes linked above. I am more curious if they ever plan on implementing `lookup filters` in LEX or not.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I view Lightning as a "public beta". It's not yet "complete" or fully defined as a platform. When Salesforce finds a need for a feature to support implementing Lightning in it the remainder of the platform, rest assured, they'll create it. Until then, we'll be somewhat at their mercy to implement what devs have identified as features essential to implementing features we see a need for. Until then, as with any other issue, we'll be left to our own devices to find a work around.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the PM for lookups in Lightning. First, I would look at your current lookup filter setup. Are they working as is? If you want to speed up Lightning or S1 adoption, try adjusting your lookup filters to not be reliant on a specific value in the field you are adding or updating.

We launched Lightning with related lookup filters support, which is by far most what admins add to their orgs. We even added support for related lookup filters Salesforce1 in Winter ’17. We think that’s a huge step in the right direction for productivity.

But, we hear you loud and clear. The lack of dependent lookup filters has been a frustrating gap. We are working on adding support for dependent lookup filters, so you’ll be able to apply your business rules automatically in the Spring '17 release. As always, #safeharbor applies, of course!